# Double Negatives with adjectives

Tags: negation, multiple-negation

I was wondering if it is correct to say:

- I am not unconfident with his answer.

By saying this I imply that I am almost not confident but I hesitate to say I am. His answer makes me hesitate.

Interesting thing:

---

As [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unconfident) says:

**ADJECTIVE**

Not confident; hesitant.
*‘the airmen were young, but not unconfident’*

Comment: I find it a puzzling way of saying something. People are more often doubtful about an answer than confident/unconfident with it - although you can be confident that it is/is not correct. The clearest way to say it is that you are unhappy/dissatisfied (or not happy/satisfied) with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English Speaker if you said this to me in conversation I would understand it to mean you have some amount of confidence but not a lot.

It is quite common to hear people speak like this but I suspect the use of this sentence is more common as the reply to a question rather than a opening sentence.

Alice: "Are you confident with his answer?"

Bob: "I am not unconfident with his answer."

In my mind the sentence is quantifying the level of confidence you have. This list shows where I understand your confidence level to be."

"I am very confident"

"I am confident"

"I am somewhat confident"

**"I am not unconfident"**

"I am unconfident"

Comment: I am not an expert on the English language and have no formal qualifications in English. I offer my advice as a native British English speaker. I believe the advice of an untrained English speaker can sometimes be beneficial

Comment: I assume that you are right. Should I say "I am not unsure if he knows it" would that mean that I doubt that he knows it but I may well be wrong?

Comment: _I am not unsure_ is far less common. You are either sure or you are not. There are different levels of confidence. being **sure** suggests extreme confidence. I would consider '_not unconfident_ almost a slang term, so it is probably best not to use it in a formal context